# Разница между ISO и GNU

Tags: c++, c++11

В настройках компилятора есть флаг `-std`, который позволяет выбрать стандарт `ISO C++11` и `GNU C++11`. Вопрос состоит в том, какая между ними разница?

Answer (score 9):

GNU расширения С++ см. [Extensions to the C++ Language](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/C_002b_002b-Extensions.html).